# How do I remove the first few rows in a table based on my time column in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table with columns: time, sum_every_5min, sum_every_10min, and sum_every_20min. How can I condition on time and replace my value in the sum every 5min, sum every 10min, and sum every 20min with NaN?

For example, for the column sum_every_5min, if the time is before 9:30, then all values in that column with time prior to 9:30 will be replaced with NaN. The other two columns remain unchanged.

Any help will be much apprecoated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a qSql update query with a where clause on the time column:

`update sum_every_5min:0Nf from t where time < 09:30`

Take a look at the kx documentation on qSql:

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/

Comment: but I am getting an error: ERROR: 'type if I try this. I made sure my time is of the form hh:mm. And my sum_every_5min contains float number rn.

Comment: specify the null as a float, edited the above. 0N will default to being a long

Comment: Got it! Thank you sooo much!